# Migrate Collections and documents from one MongoDB to another

Tags: mongodb, spring-mvc

```
**
```

> Suppose there are two mongoDb installed in two deployment location:
>       The first deployment location is server 1 and second server is Remote Desktop:
>       I know to import and export data using one collection at a time.
>       Is there any way,
>       So that i can export whole DB to JSON and import that JSON at once into 
>       another DB .
>         DB1: students ( 20 collections)  DB2: Student2:
>         Migrate all collections from Students to Student2
>   **

Comment: use replication it'll sync data between 2 dbs.

Comment: Please give one example with two DBs and query to do so . both are mongoDBs on different servers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `mongodump` and `mongorestore` utilities. Those create a binary dump of your database and preserve indexes and the likes as well.
Find more info here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongodump/

You can also dump everything in JSON format with the `mongoexport` utility and load it into another database with `mongoimport` The disadvantage is that this is 'data only' on artefacts like indices are lost. 
More info in the same reference section: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks a lot for your response.. let me try this.. then will inform you ..